# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.TabBarIOS.Item')

Tags: react-native

I upgraded from react-native 0.56.0 to 0.59.10 and i am getting this error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.TabBarIOS.Item').


2019-07-16 12:05:39.909 15028-16698/in.fr8.partner E/ReactNativeJS: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.TabBarIOS.Item')
2019-07-16 12:05:40.043 15028-16698/in.fr8.partner I/ReactNativeJS: Running application "partner" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
2019-07-16 12:05:40.044 15028-16698/in.fr8.partner E/ReactNativeJS: Application partner has not been registered.


Hint: This error often happens when you're running the packager (local dev server) from a wrong folder. For example you have multiple apps and the packager is still running for the app you were working on before.
If this is the case, simply kill the old packager instance (e.g. close the packager terminal window) and start the packager in the correct app folder (e.g. cd into app folder and run 'npm start').

This error can also happen due to a require() error during initialization or failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent.
```

Answer (score 1):

`TabBarIOS` was removed by React Native team in 0.59. Link to [changelog](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#ios-specific-14).